# Automatic install and configure

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, cloud, automation

I have many computers and sometimes I do a fresh install. There is a huge hassle to configure the computer after the install. I have tried to ease up the process by using ansible + ldap + openvpn + cups + etc...

What I want, to have all settings in the cloud like an android phone, I just type in my gmail adress and the phone just resumes where my old phone left.

Is there such a wonderful service for Ubuntu computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a BASH script that I use to do a lot of my setup stuff whenever I do a clean install.  I look it over whenever I use it to make sure nothing is specific to the version of Ubuntu I used it on last time.  With a BASH script you can add 3rd party repositories, install updates, install 3rd party software, move files around if you've got a local backup with your files on it, etc.

There's also wiki pages on automated Ubuntu installs using something called "Kickstart", found this with a quick search: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/ch04s06.html

Here's a link to an Ubuntu setup script I played around with.  This obviously doesn't configure things like Chrome or Dropbox to log into my individual accounts on those services, but it gets them installed and saves me the trouble of doing it all manually.  Feel free to copy/paste and modify this to suit your needs.  As with all free software, I'm giving this in the hopes that it will be useful, but with no guarantees, for good or ill.  Open it up and look at it before you run it so you know what it's doing.  You may want to add things to the list or take things away.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6017319/Scripts/ubuntu-setup.sh